# Is there a more efficient way to draw a chess board than this?

Tags: ios, graphics

Here's how I'm drawing a chess board in my app.  Is there a more efficient or sensible way to do this apart from using a static image?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    int verticalOffset = 40;
    int horizontalOffset = 0;
    int squareSize = 40;
    NSString *nextSquareColour = @"light";

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        // define square position
        CGRect square = {horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, squareSize, squareSize};

        // set square to be light or dark in colour
        if ([nextSquareColour isEqualToString:@"dark"]) {
            // dark square
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.80);
            nextSquareColour = @"light";
        } else {
            // light square
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.80);
            nextSquareColour = @"dark";
        }
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor
                                                   clearColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, square);
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, square);

        // set up colour and position of next square
        horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset + squareSize;
        if (i % 8 == 0) {
            verticalOffset = verticalOffset + squareSize;
            horizontalOffset = 0;
            nextSquareColour = @"dark";
        }
        if (i % 16 == 0) {
            nextSquareColour = @"light";
        }

    } // end for-loop



}
```

Comment: What about a UICollectionView, where each lines is a section, and you change the background color of the cell if `[indexPath row]+[indexPath section]` is even or not ?

Comment: OK, any comments on why I might use that instead in terms of readability/reusability/efficiency etc.?

Comment: That's just an idea. Since there is the reuse concept behind UICollectionView, the easy algorithm to determine what color to use, the `reloadData` method, etc. I don't know if it's better or not, but that may be a idea to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have performance issues unless you cause your view to redraw too many times in a limited time interval. From the look of it (a chess board) that shouldn't happen in your case.

One thing you could avoid is drawing both square colors. You could for instance set the dark color as the background and draw only the light colored squares.
Here is a little class that does it: (Colors, sizes and starting position are settable)

```
@interface ChessView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *lightSquareColor; // default is 0.95f 0.95f 0.95f 0.8f

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *darkSquareColor; // default is 0.05f 0.05f 0.05f 0.8f

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat squareSize; // default is 40.0f

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint boardOrigin; // default is {0.0f, 0.0f}

@end
```

```
@implementation ChessView

@synthesize lightSquareColor = _lightSquareColor;
@synthesize darkSquareColor = _darkSquareColor;

#pragma mark - UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)baseInit
{
    self.squareSize = 40.0f;
    self.boardOrigin = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat verticalOffset = self.boardOrigin.y;
    CGFloat horizontalOffset = self.boardOrigin.x;
    CGFloat squareSize = self.squareSize;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // draw background with dark color
    [self.darkSquareColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, squareSize * 8.0f, squareSize * 8.0f));

    // Create a path and add light squares to it
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
        CGRect square = {horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, squareSize, squareSize};
        CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, square);

        horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset + 2.0f * squareSize;
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            verticalOffset = verticalOffset + self.squareSize;
            horizontalOffset = i % 8 == 0 ? 0.0f : squareSize;
        }
    }
    [self.lightSquareColor setFill];
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

#pragma mark - Colors

- (UIColor *)lightSquareColor
{
    if (!_lightSquareColor) {
        _lightSquareColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95f
                                            green:0.95f
                                             blue:0.95f
                                            alpha:0.8f];
    }
    return _lightSquareColor;
}

- (UIColor *)darkSquareColor
{
    if (!_darkSquareColor) {
        _darkSquareColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05f
                                           green:0.05f
                                            blue:0.05f
                                           alpha:0.8f];
    }
    return _darkSquareColor;
}

- (void)setLightSquareColor:(UIColor *)lightSquareColor
{
    if (![_lightSquareColor isEqual:lightSquareColor]) {
        _lightSquareColor = lightSquareColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void)setDarkSquareColor:(UIColor *)darkSquareColor
{
    if (![_darkSquareColor isEqual:darkSquareColor]) {
        _darkSquareColor = darkSquareColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Metrics

- (void)setBoardOrigin:(CGPoint)boardOrigin
{
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(_boardOrigin, boardOrigin)) {
        _boardOrigin = boardOrigin;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void)setSquareSize:(CGFloat)squareSize
{
    if (_squareSize != squareSize) {
        _squareSize = squareSize;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: why did you use `initWithCoder` to call `baseInit`?   Why not just use `initWithFrame`?

Comment: In case you add it using interface builder `-initWithCoder:` is called and not `-initWithFrame:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want just square cells filled with solid color you can use `UIView` or `CALayer` for each cell. Set appropriate background for each view (layer) and add them to the superview (superlayer). This will consume less memory than drawing the board.

Other option is to use `CAReplicatorLayer`. But I don't see any benefit here over the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from UI, you are comparing string for so many times. You can avoid it by below way:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
     for(int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
     {
          CGRect square = {horizontalOffset  + (column * squareSize),
               verticalOffset + (row * squareSize),
               squareSize,
               squareSize};

          if((row + column) % 2 == 0)
               CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.80);
          else
               CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.80);

          CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor
                                                     clearColor].CGColor);
          CGContextFillRect(context, square);
          CGContextStrokeRect(context, square);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use line dashes, to simplify the whole thing. But i didn't check that is more performant.
Something like :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    int verticalOffset = 40;
    int horizontalOffset = 0;
    int squareSize = 40;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat dashes[2] = { squareSize, squareSize};
    CGRect boardRect = {horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, squareSize * 8, squareSize * 8};
    CGFloat halfSquareSize = squareSize * .5;

    // Fill board with light color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.80);
    CGContextFillRect(context, boardRect);

    // Draw dark squares only by using line dashes
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.80);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, squareSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ((i & 0x1) == 0)
        {
            CGContextSetLineDash(context, squareSize, dashes, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, dashes, 2);
        }

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset + i * squareSize + halfSquareSize);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, horizontalOffset + 8 * squareSize, verticalOffset + i * squareSize + halfSquareSize);

        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a predawn image that contains the whole board

Comment: Well because I might want to change the colour in user prefs so I don't want a static image